# How to use JS to scrape the page and push the variables into GTM data layers

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I'm trying to populate the Google data layer array by scraping the page using Javascript. The code below goes successfully through all items listed in HTML, as console confirms. I'm struggling to write correct dataLayer.push function that would push all three items, not just one as in my code example below.

Could someone help with this one please?

Note: You can ignore "ID" and "revenue".

```js
$("#theList li").each(function() {
  
  var $this=$(this);
  scrapeProductName=$this.find('.name').text();
  scrapeProductPrice=$this.find('.price').text();
  scrapeProductQuantity=$this.find('.quantity').text();
  
  console.log('product: ' +  scrapeProductName + '; price: ' + scrapeProductPrice + '; quantity: ' + scrapeProductQuantity);
  
});

dataLayer = [];

dataLayer.push( {
  'ecommerce': {
    'purchase': {
      'actionField': {
        'id': '11111111', 'revenue': '999.99'
      },
      'products': [
      
      // start product list
      
      {
        'name': scrapeProductName,
        'price': scrapeProductPrice,
        'quantity': scrapeProductQuantity
      }
      
      // end product list
      
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul id="theList">
  <li>
    <div class="name">banana</div>
    <div class="price">1.00</div>
    <div class="quantity">3</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="name">apple</div>
    <div class="price">2.00</div>
    <div class="quantity">5</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="name">pear</div>
    <div class="price">3.50</div>
    <div class="quantity">1</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It seems like you should do your `dataLayer.push` within the `each` function.  It also seems that the items within each `li` have conflicting ids, which may or may not cause a problem, but is definitely not best practice.

Comment: Hi @James, you're correct about IDs, those should be classes. I wrote that HTML quickly for this example because the actual page has more complex structure which is not suitable to use here. I'll correct the error now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build your products array separately in the each function, then attach it as a single entity in the dataLayer.push call:

```
var products = [];

$("#theList li").each(function() {

  var $this=$(this);
  scrapeProductName=$this.find('.name').text();
  scrapeProductPrice=$this.find('.price').text();
  scrapeProductQuantity=$this.find('.quantity').text();

  console.log('product: ' +  scrapeProductName + '; price: ' + scrapeProductPrice + '; quantity: ' + scrapeProductQuantity);

  products.push({name: scrapeProductName, price: scrapeProductPrice, quantity: scrapeProductQuantity});

});

dataLayer = [];

dataLayer.push( {
  'ecommerce': {
    'purchase': {
      'actionField': {
        'id': '11111111', 'revenue': '999.99'
      },
      'products': products
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi @James,if we push the data using js as above.Should we expect the data  that's being pushed to GTM to be shown in the GTM google chrome add on ? We tried this option and we can see the events being triggered in the network tab in developer tools in chrome but not in the google chrome GTM add on.So wondering if that suppose to show ? Please advise.